# .htaccess 301 Redirect from Old URL structure to New URL structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a user to a new URL structure.

Here's the old URL structure:

http://www.mywebsite.com/pants/pant-item-1234

Here's the new URL structure:

http://www.mywebsite.com/catalog/pants/pant-item-1234

Any idea how to do this with an HTACCESS 301 redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^pants/(.+)$ /catalog/pants/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or, if pants can actually be something else

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /catalog/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

*I haven't tested it, so I'm not sure it will work, sorry*

Answer (score 0):

Just use Rewrite URL... I wouldn't redirect unless you're not using mywebsite.com as a landing page at all. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html You will need to make sure you have your rewrite engine on.