# How to insert part of url via htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got old URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/news/newscategory/77654
```

And it should be rewritten to this URL structure:

```
http://example.com/news/newscategory/id/77654
```

So the news is static here as it's the folder. the newscategory can be something else (multiple categories). And I want to redirect the user (301) to new url with id/ part.

I fetch the url via php where the news is key, newscategory is value, id is key and number at the end is again, value.

I'm using this htaccess for this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then I use some php library to fetch the values.

Edit: What I'm asking is that I want to redirect user from first url to second one so that I can fetch the id.

The first link is already working, but I still have links to the old url structure that leads to category view. Live urls:

old structure: http://www.autonet.ee/uudised/paevauudised/77665

new structure: http://www.autonet.ee/uudised/paevauudised/id/77665

the old one should redirect user to the new link.

Comment: Are you asking for help writing Apache RewriteRules that will turn the `newscategory` and numeric id into GET variables for index.php, or are you looking for help writing the PHP component that will parse the original query string?  Your question does not appear to ask an actual *question*, and while you've included some Apache configuration, you haven't included and code, or an explanation of either the problem you're having or where you'd like to end up.  Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38943771/edit) and add these important pieces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add /id/ in /news/... URLS
RewriteRule ^(news/[^\w-]+)/(\d+)$ /$1/id/$2 [R=301,L,NC]

# front controller rule    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule if i understand correctly

```
RewriteRule ^([.*])/([.*])/([.*])/([.*])$ index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4
```

please explain if missed something.

**EDIT**

okay, according to you news and id are static but their value is dynamic please try the rule below

```
RewriteRule ^(news)/([.*])/(id)/([.*])$ index.php?news=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That one is redirecting /1/2/3/4/ to regular get url. What I need is to redirect user from http://example.com/news/newscategory/77654 to http://example.com/news/newscategory/id/77654 so I can fetch the id parameter. The old code of the website was using the url structure without id, the new one is using it with id. So when user visits the old url he does not get the single news item, but rather the category as the id is not passed as value. My htaccess/php code is giving me the option to have /key/value/key/value/ urls and I want to use that.

Comment: Something like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490416/htaccess-301-redirect-from-old-url-structure-to-new-url-structure but in my case RewriteRule `^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1/$2/id [R=301,L]` id is added to the end, I want to add it before the last part of url. I'm pretty bad with regex :(

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar, what do you think `([.*])` will match?