# redirect 200+ links to new webshop

Tags: php, redirect

I have an old web-shop and a new one. I want to link all my old links (about 200 links) to the new web shop.

My old links look like: `www.mydomain.nl/index.php?item=lip-perfection-ultra-reflex-7-ml&action=article&group_id=10000020&aid=61&lang=NL`

My new links look like: webshop.mydomain.nl/Pupa-Lip-Perfection-Ultra-Reflex-7-ml

I have tried .htaccess, but it stops after `index.php`

How can i redirect my links?

Comment: top of your index.php script - `header("Location: https://webshop.mydomain.nl/" . $_GET['item'])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess 301 Redirect from Old URL structure to New URL structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490416/htaccess-301-redirect-from-old-url-structure-to-new-url-structure)